# Doing string startswith/endswith in C

Tags: c

To see if one string contains another I can do :

```
strstr("this is my line of text", "th") != NULL;
```

How would I check to see if a line of text starts with the substring? What about if a string endswith a sub-string?

Comment: Use `strncmp(s, prefix, strlen(prefix))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starts With:

```
strncmp(s, prefix, strlen(prefix)) == 0
```

(thanks to jamesdlin)

Ends with is harder though. Helper function:

```
/* return 0 for match, nonzero for no match */
int stringendswith(const char *s, const char *t)
{
    size_t slen = strlen(s);
    size_t tlen = strlen(t);
    if (tlen > slen) return 1;
    return strcmp(s + slen - tlen, t);
}
```

Comment: I think `stringendswith` should return non-zero if it matches, as this will match the behaviour for other "boolean-like" functions in C, such as `isdigit` etc. Otherwise, if you read `if (stringendwith(s, ".pdf")) { ... }`, I think most people would expect it to branch if the `s` ended with `.pdf`, but in this case, it will branch if it *doesn't*.

Comment: @dreanlax: I matched `strcmp` but OP can do as he chooses.

Comment: Oh OK, I see what you were going for. Although I would argue that `strcmp` does not return a Boolean result, it returns whether the first string lexicographically compares less than (<0), equal to (0), or greater than (>0) the second string, but you're right, ultimately it's up to the author!